# Weird XML File Created

Tags: c#, xml

I created a .XML file through this code:
[image]

After I created that, I've opened my .XML file and it looks like this:
[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please provide your code as text in the question not in images, so we can copy it and try the code out

Comment: Attributes have to be an array object : var Alumo = new XElement("aluno", new object[] { new XAttribute(.......

Comment: `enter image description here` isn't valid C#. Please tag with whatever language you're actually using.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new `XElement` named `Aluno`, but you're adding `aluno` (without the capital A) to the document.

Comment: That's a difficult to spot bug, caused by bad variable naming.

Comment: You were right, i missed that, thanks for the help.  It's all right now, thanks for your time